# Crank-Nicolson Scheme Not giving Accuracy of Order 2

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, quantum-mechanics, finite-differences

I've been trying to figure out what the issue is in my numerical scheme I've written to solve the particle in the box problem for the Schrodinger equation. I've used a Crank-Nicolson scheme to implicitly solve for the wave function numerically. The issue I'm running into is that the Crank-Nicolson scheme is second order accurate in space, but I'm only finding that my numerical solution is somewhere between first and second order accurate. I am nearly 100% positive that the Crank-Nicolson scheme is of order (2,2) for the Schrodinger equation, just like the heat equation, and that there should be no special exceptions here. Because of this, I'm assuming there's an error somewhere in my code for solving of the numerical solution. I'm determining the order of accuracy by checking if the following ration holds.
$$
\frac{O\left(\left(\dfrac{1}{2} \Delta x\right)^2\right)}{O(\Delta x^2)} \approx \frac{1}{4}
$$
The scheme I derived from the Schrodinger equation
$$
i \partial_t \psi(t,x) = -\frac{1}{2} \partial_x^2 \psi(t,x)
$$
is given by
$$
\textbf{A}\psi^{n+1} = -\textbf{A}^{*}\psi^{n}
$$
And $\textbf{A}$ is the tridiagonal matrix given by
$$
\textbf{A}_{jk} =
\begin{cases}
-2 + i \cdot 2/\mu, & j = k\\
1, & |j-k|=1\\
0, & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
And $\mu = \Delta t/\Delta x^2$. The lack of potential term, $V(x)$, in the original Schrodinger equation is because I'm writing this for the particle in the box problem, and the potential's conditions are enforced via the boundary conditions, since there is no tunneling outside the "walls of the box".
My scheme is written in MATLAB here

```
function [wave_function_final, wave_function, error] = Schrodinger_CrankNicolson_PIAB(h,k,T,xL,xR,N)
    m = ceil((xR - xL)/h); % Number of x-axis intervals
    h = (xR - xL)/m;
    n = ceil(T/k); % Number of t-axis intervals
    k = T/n;
    mu = k/h^2;
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % natural units ---> MASS = 1, hbar = 1
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    DiagTerm = -2*(1 - 1i*2/mu);
    
    A = diag(DiagTerm*ones(1,m-1)) + diag(ones(1,m-2),1) + diag(ones(1,m-2),-1);
    
    B = -conj(A);
    
    wave_function = zeros(n+1,m-1);
    
    x_val = xL + h*(1:m-1);
    wave_function(1,:) = sqrt(2/(xR - xL))*sin(N*pi/(xR-xL) * (x_val - xL));
    
    for tstep = 2:(n+1)
        wave_function(tstep,:) = ((A.'*A)\A.'*B * wave_function(tstep-1,:).').';
    end
    
    wave_function = [zeros(n+1,1), wave_function, zeros(n+1,1)]; % <-- Concatenates Columns to the left and right of wave_function for boundary conditions
    
    wave_function_final = wave_function(end,:);
    
    En = (N*pi)^2/8;
    
    error = sqrt(sum( abs( exp(-1i*En*T)*wave_function(1,1:end) - wave_function_final(1:end) ).^2));
    
    
end
```

In my function $\Delta t = k$ and $\Delta x = h$. And I run it using the script

```
xL = -1;
xR = 1;
N = 1;
rev = 2*pi;
En = (N*pi)^2/8;
T = rev/En;
M = [10, 20, 40, 80];
Errors = zeros(1,length(M));
orders = zeros(1,length(M)-1);

tic
parfor i=1:length(M)
    h = 1/M(i);
    k = 1/10000;
    [wave_function_final, wave_function, error] = Schrodinger_CrankNicolson_PIAB(h,k,T,xL,xR,N);
    Errors(i) = error;
end

for i=1:length(orders)
    orders(i) = Errors(i+1)/Errors(i);
end

disp(orders)
```

The values in my vector `orders` are all on approximately equal to $0.35$. When in reality these should be approximately $0.25$. I keep my value of $k$ $(\Delta t)$ low so that the error changing should only be that of space and not time. Ultimately, I don't know what's going on as I cannot personally find any problems in the code but I know my order of accuracy should still be much better.

Scheme Background (indirectly solving the Schrodinger equation by means of the evolution of initial wave state).

The choice for the time evolution is $e^{-i H t/\hbar}$,using Cayley's approximation of an exponential gives
$$
\hat{U}(t) = e^{-i H t/\hbar} \approx \frac{1 - \frac{1}{2\hbar} i H t}{1 + \frac{1}{2\hbar} i H t}
$$
which is unitary. Solving the Schrodinger equation at this points amounts to numerically solving the ODE:
$$
\psi(t+\Delta t,\vec{x}) = \hat{U}(\Delta t) \psi(t,\vec{x}) = \frac{1 - \frac{1}{2\hbar} i H \Delta t}{1 + \frac{1}{2\hbar} i H \Delta t} \psi(t,\vec{x})
$$
which can be rewritten as
$$
\left( 1 + \frac{1}{2\hbar} i H \Delta t \right) \psi(t+\Delta t,\vec{x}) = \left(1 - \frac{1}{2\hbar} i H \Delta t \right) \psi(t,\vec{x})
$$

EDIT #1: Removed unnecessary derivations, not overly relevant.

EDIT #2: Used clearer indices so not to confuse $i$ the index with $i$ the number

Comment: You're freezing the time step size and shrinking the space step size? This will eventually stop working the way you expect.

Comment: This is true, but the k size stays sufficiently small for the values of h used. Also I've run the same script with k = 1/M^2, (M is the list of values in the script), and I get the same exact order values.

Comment: So you tried larger time steps? I am concerned about possibly running into stability problems with many small steps, hence an interest in slightly larger steps.

Comment: Also, what's the boundary condition for the original PDE, and how are you implementing it in the method?

Comment: Your line where you actually do the time updates looks weird to me, can you explain what's going on there?

Comment: It seems to me that you should have $\frac{i}{\Delta t}(\psi^{(n+1)}-\psi^{(n)})=\frac{1}{2} \left ( -\frac{1}{2} \nabla^2 \psi^{(n+1)} - \frac{1}{2} \nabla^2 \psi^{(n)} \right )$ where $\nabla^2$ is whatever second differencing matrix you use. Rearranging you get $\left ( \frac{i}{\Delta t} I + \frac{1}{4} \nabla^2 \right ) \psi^{(n+1)} = \frac{i}{\Delta t} \psi^{(n)} - \frac{1}{4} \nabla^2 \psi^{(n)}$, then $\psi^{(n+1)}$ is formally $\left ( \frac{i}{\Delta t} I + \frac{1}{4} \nabla^2 \right )^{-1} \left ( \frac{i}{\Delta t} I - \frac{1}{4} \nabla^2 \right ) \psi^{(n)}$.

Comment: I guess now you pull out the $\frac{i}{\Delta t}$ to get $\left ( I - \frac{i \Delta t}{4} \nabla^2 \right )^{-1} \left ( I + \frac{i \Delta t}{4} \nabla^2 \right ) \psi^{(n)}$.

Comment: I can go through the derivation of the scheme, but it's a tad lengthy.

Comment: I'm not asking about the derivation of Crank-Nicolson, just the application to this problem. It looks wrong to me, I got something that doesn't look the same when I tried to do it myself and wrote it above. But I may be carelessly reading your code.

Comment: Sorry you lost me in technicalities in your edit.

Comment: It might have to do with the use of the evolution operator usage when deriving the scheme. The scheme is derived slightly different from that of the heat equation. You need a unitary operator to evolve the initial state or else the probability isn't conserved which is 100% necessary when dealing with a wave function.

Comment: I mean if it's Crank-Nicolson it's still the same setup, like what I said above. Either way if you have $\partial_t u = F(u,x,t,\partial_x u,\partial_{xx} u)$ then Crank-Nicolson says use $\frac{u^{n+1}_i-u^n_i}{\Delta t}=\frac{1}{2} \left ( F(u^n_i,x_i,t_n,(\partial_x u^n)_i,(\partial_{xx} u^n)_i) + F(u^{n+1}_i,x_i,t_{n+1},(\partial_x u^{n+1})_i,(\partial_{xx} u^{n+1})_i) \right )$. That's what Crank-Nicolson *is*.

Comment: You can read this if you don't want to go through the hassle of reading my derivation for Crank-Nicolson for the Schrodinger: https://web.physics.utah.edu/~detar/phycs6730/handouts/crank_nicholson/crank_nicholson/

Comment: Looks the same. That still doesn't explain this (A.'*A)\A.'*B thing. Why can't you just do A\\(B\*...)? It'll be computationally cheaper that way anyway.

Comment: I could definitely do that, I had that in there in situations where I might write another scheme (not CN)  where A isn't square. I just checked with A\B and the orders are still ~0.35

Comment: Looks like Carl Christian has you covered on your actual question. On this thing about the non-square case, FYI Matlab does least squares by default with backslash. Even without this handy feature of Matlab, you should never assemble the normal equations numerically. It is a condition number catastrophe when you do that. You should always do least squares with a better conditioned algorithm (e.g. QR decomposition, or SVD).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are computing the Euclidean norm of the vector that contains the pointwise errors. Each component is essentially $O(h^2)$ where $h$ is the spatial stepsize. In your minimal working example the time step has been reduced to the point where it makes a neglible contribution to the error. Therefore your error behaves as $$E(m,h)=\sqrt{m}h^2$$ where $m$ is the length of the vector and $h$ and $mh$ is a constant, the length of your interval. Your order is computed as the ratio $$E(2m,h/2)/E(m,h) = \frac{\sqrt{2m} \frac{1}{4} h^2}{\sqrt{m} h^2} = \sqrt{2} \frac{1}{4} \approx 0.35.$$
You are getting exactly the results that you should.

---

Your objective is to compute an approximation of a function $$x \rightarrow f(T,x)$$ for some fixed value $t=T$ of the time. You have approximations $a_j$ of $f(T,x_j)$ for equidistant $x_j$, i.e., $x_j = x_0 + jh$. The global error is $$e_j = f(T,x_j) - a_j = O(k^2 + h^2).$$ You have reduced the temporal stepsize $k$ to the point where it is irrelevant. I would like you to compute either $$E_1 = h \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} |e_j|$$ or $$E_2 = \sqrt{h \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} e_j^2}.$$ Both expressions are of class $O(h^2)$ because $mh = x_R - x_L$ is a constant. [Note: You should be using $m$ to compute $h$, rather than the other way around using the ceiling function. It is not a significant issue here, it will show up in a test based on Richardson's techniques.] Your original/new measure is $$\tilde{E} = \sqrt{\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} e_j^2} = O(\sqrt{mh^4}) = O(\sqrt{m}h^2) = O(h^{\frac{3}{2}}).$$

Comment: I replaced `error = sqrt(sum( abs( exp(-1i*En*T)*wave_function(1,1:end) - wave_function_final(1:end) ).^2));` with `error = norm( exp(-1i*En*T)*wave_function(1,1:end) - wave_function_final(1:end) );`, I actually ended up doing this last night, when I was trying to clean up my code. Unfortunately, I still get ~0.35 in my orders. Was this what you wanted me to change? Also, could you explain a little more how the number of intervals ($m$) affects the error, or link a site that shows its contribution in the calculation?

Comment: @DavidG. I added some extra material.

Comment: Thank you! I was calculating the error as if the function itself was an actual vector whereas it was just being stored as one, the extra $h$ resolved that immediately.

Comment: @DavidG. You are very welcome.